# Postgres age in different languages

Tags: postgresql, translation

Every day I love Postgres a little bit more, today I found the function "age".
Instead of just selecting the years, it also selects months and days. Wonderful!

```
46 years 10 mons 18 days
```

Now I´m wondering is there a function to define the words 'years', 'mons', 'days'.
The best solution would be somekind of `date_style` to get this words in different languages. This would make it possible to let my backend return the correct translation and not configure it in the front end.

If its not possible I will do it with `date_part` and add the translation in the `front_end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language used is taken from the host environment locale settings.

You can set the language that will be used at db initialization.

```
eg. initdb --locale=sv_SE
```

[documentation 23.1. Locale Support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/locale.html)

Comment: Ah cool solution for 1 language, badly not for multiple. Only if I run multiple databases. But still helpfull ty.